# Revolving a $k$-manifold around an axis gives a $(k+1)$-manifold

Tags: analysis, differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

I want to solve the following problem from M. Spivak's Calculus on Manifolds:

> Let $\mathbb{K}^n=\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n:x^1=0 \text{ and }x^2>0,\dots,x^{n-1}>0\}$. If $M \subseteq \mathbb{K}^n$ is a $k$-dimensional manifold, and $N$ is obtained by revolving $M$ around the axis $x^1=\cdots=x^{n-1}=0$, show that $N$ is a $(k+1)$ dimensional manifold. Example: the Torus (Figure 5-4).

**My attempt:**

At first I considered the case $n=3$, where $\mathbb{K}^3=\{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3:x=0,y>0\}$.

for a point $\mathbf{x}$ not on the $z$ axis consider the angle $\theta(\mathbf{x})$ which is the one between the vector projection of $\mathbf{x}$ to the $[xy]$ plane and the positive $x$-axis (this is the angle $\theta$ from polar coordinates).

Now, since $M$ is $1$-dimensional manifold, for each $p \in M$ there exists open sets $U_p \ni p,V_p \subseteq \mathbb{R}^3$ and a diffeomorphism $h_p:U_p \to V_p$ such that $h_p(U_p \cap M)=V_p \cap (\mathbb{R}^1 \times \{0\}^2 )$.

Let $q \in N$ be some point. Define $$k_q(\mathbf{x}):=[R_z(\theta(\mathbf{x})) \circ h \circ R_z(-\theta(\mathbf{x}))](\mathbf{x})$$

where $R_z$ is the rotation matrix around the $z$-axis, and a branch of $\theta$ is chosen so that it is smooth around $q$. Say $p$ is the (unique) point in $\mathbb{K}^3$ such that $q$ is the result of some rotation of it around the $z$-axis. If $U_p$ is taken

to be a sufficiently small ball around $p$ (so that it doesn't intersect the $z$-axis), I claim that $k_q$ is a diffeomorphism with domain $\overline{U}_q:=R_z(\theta(q))[U_p]$ and codomain $\overline{V}_q:=k_q(\overline{U}_q)$. I also claim that

$$k_q(\overline{U}_q \cap N)=\overline{V}_q \cap (\mathbb{R}^2 \times \{0\}) .$$

---

*Now, trying to generalize this to arbitrary $n$ seems difficult to me, as I have no idea how rotations in $\geq 4$ dimensions work.*

---

My questions are:

1. Is the proof for $n=3$ valid? If not,  please help me correct it.
2. How can one prove the general case?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you have available the Rank Theorem?

Comment: Alternatively, do you know the fact that the Cartesian product of two manifolds is again a manifold?

Comment: @Travis I'm not sure what rank theorem you are referring to, and I don't know that fact about the product.

Comment: I see---is the only way you have avaiable to show that a topological space is a manifold is the definition (e.g., showing the existence of local charts, Hausdorffness, and second countability)?

Comment: @Travis This is an introductory text on manifolds. They were defined as subsets of some euclidean n-space such that for any point on them there is a diffeomorphism that maps the part of the manifold to the part of the codomain with last $n-k$ coordinates=0.

Comment: The dimensions seems to be wrong. Or did Spivak define what he means by rotating around an axis? Or did you copy the problem correctly? I ask because the natural interpretation of "rotating around an axis" for a one-dimensional axis ($x^1 = \cdots = x^{n-1} = 0$) is an action by $SO(n-1)$ whose orbits are spheres with dimension $n-2$, so the dimension seems to be wrong. To gain one dimension as asked for one would want to consider an $U(1)$ action, which would be rotating around a codimension-2 axis.

Comment: @WillieWong you can find the problem on page 115 [here](http://faculty.ksu.edu.sa/fawaz/482/Books/Spivak_Calculus%20on%20manifolds.pdf).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am about 99.9% sure that the problem statement is wrong.

1. The question makes no sense for $n = 2$.
2. The orbits of the "revolution" around a one dimensional axis in $\mathbb{R}^n$ are $n-2$ dimensional spheres. This indicates that for a $0$-dimensional manifold $M$, its rotation $N$ becomes $n-2$ dimensional which for $n > 3$ is strictly larger than $1 = k+1$.

I am about 99.9% sure that the correct problem statement is the following:

> Let $n \geq 2$ and $\mathbb{K}^n = \{ x\in \mathbb{R}^n| x^1 = 0, x^2 > 0\}$ and let $M\subset \mathbb{K}^n$ be an $k$-dimensional submanifold. Show that the set $N$ obtained by revolving $M$ around the axis $x^1 = x^2 = 0$ is a $k+1$ dimensional manifold.

Note that when $n = 3$ the two formulations of the problems agree. Note further that this version makes sense also for $n = 2$. The notion of revolution is clear once you restrict to a co-dimension 2 axis: it is the action by the matrices

$$ R_{12}(\theta) = \begin{pmatrix} 
\cos \theta & \sin\theta & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
- \sin\theta & \cos\theta & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & & &\ddots  & 0 \\
0 & & \cdots & & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix} $$

and the proof in 3D basically carries over to arbitrary dimensions with very little modification. (In fact, you can start with the proof in 2D and carry it up to arbitrary dimensions.)

(One particularly simple proof uses the the "cylindrical" coordinates on $\mathbb{R}^n \setminus \{x^1 = x^2 = 0\}$ which is the same as the usual Euclidean coordinate system except $(x^1,x^2)$ is replaced by $(r = \sqrt{(x^1)^2 + (x^2)^2}, \theta = \arctan x^2/x^1)$.)

Comment: Thank you Willie. Since I'm not fluent with high dimensions, I'm more interested in my proof for the n=3 case. What are your thoughts about it?

Comment: In terms of basic construction, what I outlined in the parenthetical in the bottom of my answer is the same as your proof but in perhaps (to me at least) slightly more transparent notation. Obviously if you are turning it in for homework your write-up would need to be a bit more detailed (justifying the few "claims"), but the basic structure of your sketch is sound. // If you are familiar with the characterisation of submanifolds in terms of defining functions, then you can also invoke a defining function of $M\hookrightarrow \mathbb{K}^n$ and rotate it to obtain a defining function

Comment: (cont'd) of $N\hookrightarrow \mathbb{R}^n \setminus \{x_1 = x_2 = 0\}$. In terms of the torus example, this would be saying that the circle is the set $\{ (x^2-2)^2 + (x^3)^2 -1 = 0\}\subset \mathbb{K}^n$ and the torus is the set $\{ (r-2)^2 + (x^3)^2 - 1 = 0\} \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ where $r = \sqrt{(x^1)^2 + (x^2)^2}$.